# Delete everything after second comma from string

Tags: r, regex, string

I would like to remove anything after the second comma in a string -including the second comma-. Here is an example:

```
x <- 'Day,Bobby,Jean,Gav'
gsub("(.*),.*", "\\1", x)
```

and it gives:

```
[1] "Day, Bobby, Jean"
```

while I want:

```
[1] "Day, Bobby
```

regardless of the number of names that may exist in `x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
> x <- 'Day, Bobby, Jean, Gav'
> sub("^([^,]*,[^,]*),.*", "\\1", x)
[1] "Day, Bobby"
```

The `^([^,]*,[^,]*),.*` pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `([^,]*,[^,]*)` - Group 1: 0+ non-commas, a comma, and 0+ non-commas
- `,.*`   - a comma and the rest of the string.

The `\1` in  the replacement pattern will keep Group 1 value in the result.

Comment: thank you for the explanation and the answer

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `strsplit` and then `paste`

```
toString(head(strsplit(x, ",")[[1]], 2))
#[1] "Day, Bobby"
```